# Spacy similarity score for sweet M&M fails

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, similarity

python 3 spacy seems to have a problem with sweets such as M&Ms.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg" )

query = nlp( "M&M" )
query2 = nlp("M&M chocolate pouch")
print( "Score of M&M versus the full name in shop:", query2.similarity(query) )
```

The resultant score returned is ***0.0***. And if query2 is any possible string, the result is always 0.0.

However, if you space separate M&M to make "M & M" then the scores are reasonable.

Does anyone know why it fails with a large language model on such a confectionary? And is there a solution to find the correct similarity score without synthetically adding in spaces around the ampersand?

Answer (score 2):

You can install spacy v3.4+ and download the compatible `en_core_web_lg` pipeline with `spacy download`, which should include a vector for the token `M&M`.

The v3.3 and earlier `en_core_web_md/lg` models have vectors from a different source and don't contain the token `M&M`.

These pipelines contain tables of static word embeddings for a fixed token list, they're not large language models.

```
print( "Version:", spacy.__version__ )
query = nlp( "M & M" )
query2 = nlp("M&M chocolate pouch")
print( "Score of %s versus %s is %f" % ( query, query2, query2.similarity(query) ) ) 
query = nlp( "M&M" )
query2 = nlp("M&M chocolate pouch")
print( "Score of %s versus %s is %f" % ( query, query2, query2.similarity(query) ) )
```

Output is:

```
Version: 3.5.0
Score of M & M versus M&M chocolate pouch is 0.053697
Score of M&M versus M&M chocolate pouch is 0.616930
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been using 3.2.4 installed using Conda and pip for some time now. I performed a pip install -U on spacy and then downloaded the two newer language models as you suggested.